# Does GoDaddy support Microsoft Chart Controls

Tags: web-development, web-hosting, godaddy, windows, microsoft

Does anyone know (or have running) if Chart Controls will work on GoDaddy's Windows Servers. They have ASP.NET 4.0 but is that enough?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoDaddy only has medium trust for ASP.NET apps and you will need a high level of trust. Also, I've heard you can't run MSChart.exe with GoDaddy and a lot of people have left GoDaddy just because of this.

On a side note, slightly unrelated, GoDaddy's hosting is absolutely terrible, but that's just my two cents.

Comment: thanks, what is the best windows host for the price that would support the chart controls?

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't tell you. I am not too terribly familiar with windows hosting.